NextJS with NextAuth.js custom API methods
I am making panel with NextAuth, and I wonder how can I use it in API routes?
I need to get users email or anything to work with database.
Documentation has only in NextJS "pages" API, but I am on app router.
The API routes code:
import { authOptions } from "pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]"
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)

  if (!session) {
    res.status(401).json({ message: "You must be logged in." })
    return
  }

  return res.json({
    message: "Success",
  })
}


Whats your problem right now? The documentation also have App Routes example https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#in-api-routes? What problem that you encounter?
